# Wanted to print All ID and relate Parent id, but parent id is not marked any where

Tags: sql

Based on the condition we need to mark Related Parent id suggestion

instead of inputing 1st query to second query, can we print all the id and related parent id suggestion list

1. I wrote a query to get the type 1 relates id's here

```
select id 
  from **Task_table** 
 where date = '${date}'  
   and type = 1  
   and version >= 1 
   and status = 2;


Output:

id
----
123
234
456
```

2. I wrote another query to, if I pass 123 as input:

```
-- here {{input_id}} is from query1

set hivevar:input_id= {{input_id}};
SET hivevar:table1_name = (SELECT get_json_object(conf, '$.configuration.operator.parameter.tableName') FROM **Task_table** WHERE date = '${date}' AND id = ${input_id} LIMIT 1);

--select ${table1_name}
SELECT ${input_id} As ID,id As Related_Parent_Id
FROM **Task_table**
WHERE date = '20231206' 
AND conf LIKE CONCAT('%', ${table1_name}, '%')


Output
---
id , Related_Parent_id
123    789
123   893
```

```
I wanted Output like complete ids' related outputs ,

id , Related_Parent_id
123   789
123   893
234   334
234   766
234   900
345   411
```

Comment: 1) MySQL <> SQL Server - please tag the correct RDBMS.

Comment: 2) Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags here. The SQL implies it's Hive, which isn't even either of the products you tagged. This suggests that you have no idea what you are actually using. I suggest finding out first, and then improving your question.

Comment: Are **Task_table** in query 1 and **Task_table** in query 2 referring to the same table? If so, why two queries?

Comment: `LIMIT 1` without an `ORDER BY` gives an arbitrary row (no guarantee it's the same one each time), is that intentional?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
  task_with_table AS
(
  SELECT
    task.id,
    (
      SELECT
        get_json_object(
          conf,
          '$.configuration.operator.parameter.tableName'
        )
      FROM
        task_table
      WHERE
            date = task.date
        AND id   = task.input_id
      LIMIT
        1
    )
      AS task_table_name
  FROM
    task_table   AS task
  WHERE
        task.date     = '${date}'
    AND task.type     = 1
    AND task.version >= 1
    AND task.status   = 2
)
SELECT
  child.id,
  parent.id   AS related_parent_id
FROM
  task_with_table   AS child
INNER JOIN
  task_table        AS parent
    ON  parent.date = '20231206'
    AND parent.conf LIKE CONCAT('%', child.task_table_name, '%')
```

The correlated sub-query looks suspect though.  It has no `ORDER BY` and ***appears*** as though you could just look it up from the same row that gave you the `id`.